# google account signin using firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, cors

after adding the firebaseconfig to the environement.prod, and when i started to testing the signin with google , i get an cors errors saying that acccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OUFjF8Q' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.i have deployed my backend in heroku and before i add the firebase it's work perfetcly , any help please

i'm newer in using ionic firebase and google i need help

Comment: There are a lot of very similar questions here on SO. See [these Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+is+present+on+the+requested+resource). It's a good idea to do a bit of research before posting questions as it may have already been asked.

Comment: thank you , in fact i have make a lot of research , i didn't get the solution